# Does moss require darkness when grown indoors?

Tags: plant-care, growth, light, moss, grow-lamp

People always say that moss prefers to grow in (moist) dark, dappled, shady, or otherwise low-light conditions. Strictly speaking, I don't believe that's the case. 
I think in a natural environment it generally tends to appear that way; mainly because constant, full sunlight will typically consist of significant amounts of UV & IR radiation, in addition to visible spectra.

Even more significant (I think) is the implied rate of water/moisture evaporation, that moss is sensitive to.

My hypothesis is that moss (if kept moist), grown indoors, under a bright LED light, isolated from harmful UV & IR radiation, should thrive.

My question is twofold: a) Do you agree; and if so: b) Will moss grow better under these conditions 24/7, or 12/7?

Comment: I think you've already had an answer that suggests most plants prefer a period of darkness in 24 hours - why don't you experiment and see which works,if it works at all?

Comment: Oh, do you think so? I think you're mistaken; I haven't received any answers yet. Anyway, I'm looking for facts, not suggestions. I'm currently trying a few different things myself, but this is moss growth were talking about; it's not exactly a speedy process.

Comment: This question was well made, tj!  We'll work on this...

Comment: This was interesting during my travels.  Maybe you've already seen this...and it is from SE!  Doesn't answer your questions but should be up your alley.  Still working on this...

Comment: Looks like my site did not get pasted correctly, grrrr.  I am an airhead half the time.  Check these sites out as well; https://www.quora.com/Do-plants-need-darkness-Can-they-survive-in-indefinite-sunlight  http://www.mossandstonegardens.com/blog/how-to-grow-moss/

Comment: Here is the site that didn't get posted that is from kevinsky on this site 2012  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/what-kind-of-light-is-needed-for-moss-and-ferns?rq=1

Comment: Yes. Plants has an diurnal cycle just like animals. They need darkness to reset the biochemical mechanisms and rebuilt the enzymes needed for the Krebs cycle. It always surprise they need dark, but it is really quite obvious. I mean, look at where they evolved ;)  (from Quora)

Comment: It depends on the plant. Most plants won't react too well to too much light. After all they have evolved to use the dark.Also short day flowering plants need dark cycles to reproduce, long day flowering plants need it to vegetate.Study the plant you are growing and find out what climates it does best in, and try to simulate or optimize those light cycles.18/6 (18 hours of light, 6 hours of dark) for veg and 12/12 for flowering will work quite well for most short day flowering plants.Also ensure that your dark cycles are 100% dark, no light!

Comment: Or the plant may get stressed. If you must inspect your plants during the dark period, use green lights.   (another answer from Quora)

Comment: My opinion is that darkness is as important to plants as it is for animals.  This last answer, from someone else actually used the word 'reset'.  So much happens during dark yet we sometimes forget or haven't been told what that is down to the cellular level.  This Quora site is fascinating and huge.  But in essence, all of life based on sunlight and then darkness has evolved to thrive with both.  24/7 light is never a good thing for humans nor plants.  My opinion.  Surprised that there is so little information as to the WHY at the cellular level.  Krebs cycle information says a bit about dark

Answer (score 2):

[Moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moss) is one of the most adaptable organisms as far as amount of light, moisture, soil type and location.

They are found from the Arctic to the [Antarctic](https://bogology.org/2013/10/16/how-do-mosses-survive-in-antarctica/) and survive extended days of total darkness and almost total light.  However the key word is survive.

I cannot find any research proving that they need a period of darkness but it has been proven with their vascular cousins that some plants need a daily period of darkness to initiate flowering.  As moss does not flower they might do well with 24 hours of light.  See this extended discussion [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_happens_to_a_plant_that_is_kept_under_constant_light2) for the technicalities of photosynthesis.  For a more accessible article on moss this [one](http://www.mossandstonegardens.com/blog/the-truth-about-moss-dispelling-moss-myths/) is more amusing and concise.

Moss will grow fine in full sunlight if adequate moisture is supplied.  I can take a piece of moss from the north facing dry part of my garden and put in the sunny moist area.  It doubles in size and will even grow into the water and float on top.

When growing inside it is not enough to have it moist and bright.  You need air circulation as well.

Moss picture from my garden[image: moss from my water garden]

Answer (score 1):

Plants need certain light spectra, typically some from each the red and blue ranges. An incandescent puts out a full range ( typically) , but fluorescent and LED put out specific narrow ranges. One place you can find this information is lighting for aquarium plants. I have moss just like your photo and it thrives on  indirect natural light all day . My hunch is that it does not need a dark period and the spectra is important.