# Question about illumination for moss

Tags: indoors, light, moss

I'm about to open my store and I built my logo with moss in a coconut fiber board (sticking little parts of moss with gardening wire to the board).

I wanna hang it on the wall and direct a light towards it. I have no idea how to illuminate it.

My store will be opened for 12h in the future, so I'd leave this light directed to it for those 12h (and moss should only get about 2 hours of sunlight / day)

I figured I could just buy those light supports for artwork (60cm long).

[image: Light support arm 60cm]

The thing is, it normally only comes in with LED. I saw [this other thread](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/what-kind-of-light-is-needed-for-moss-and-ferns) where @Kevinsky explains the impact of different types of light for moss in a typical terrarium. He doesn't mention LED though. Would it work?

In this thread, he also mentions that Xenon would it make it look better. But I only found Xenon lamps for cars and parties. Not sure if I'm poorly searching.

Another important theme is the watering of the moss, I plan to water it by sprikling water directly on it. Filtered water, every 12h (and it would not be watered in sundays). Is this a problem at all? It is normal filtered water, should I add in something to make it healthier?

I put in A LOT of work to build my logo with this, I really want it to be healthy for a long time and to look good on the wall. Thanks for everyone willing to help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you not use live moss but instead use "[modelling moss](https://www.amazon.co.uk/modelling-moss/s?k=modelling%20moss)". This is used by model railroad hobbyists to create shrubs, trees, even grass on their train layouts (it's actually a type of dyed lichen). It certainly make it much easier to maintain your logo board than trying to keep ground moss alive in a vertical, non-natural environment.

Comment: Kind of too late... https://imgur.com/a/FUIrWXj